# dynamic variable not accepting inherited properties without typecasting

Tags: c#

I have this dynamic variable by which I serialize a json string.

```
dynamic result = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);
```

From this I am fetching `result["success"]` which resolves as `Dictionary<string, object>` at runtime. I then applied the namespace `System.Linq` so that I may call `.First()` on the variable.
I wrote

```
KeyValuePair<string, object> temp = result["success"].First();
```

Then I got the error,

> 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary' does not contain a definition for 'First'

(But it does, with LINQ, right?) Now I changed the code like this.

```
KeyValuePair<string, object> temp = 
    ((Dictionary<string, object>)result["success"]).First();
```

It ran without any glitches. So I thought it might be because of the dynamically resolved variable. Then I tried with a native property of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` like this

```
var foo = result["success"].Keys;
```

This too ran without any glitches and it got me confused and hence this post.

What I understood is that dynamically resolved variables only accept *native properties* and needs typecasting for *inherited properties*.

My doubts are

1. Is my understanding correct?
2. Is this the expected behaviour?
3. If so, why is it so?

P.S: Coding in C# 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because *extension methods* are *syntactic sugars*. When you call `First` on a dictionary like this:

```
dictionary.First();
```

Compiler translates it into:

```
Enumerable.First(dictionary);
```

But in this case since the type is `dynamic`, compiler doesn't know anything about `First`.Or in other words it doesn't check whether there is an extension method named `First` and attempt to translate the code to a normal method call.At runtime it looks for an *instance* method. And because type does not have any instance method named `First`, you get the exception. To fix this you just need to call your method as a normal instead of extension like already stated in Jon Skeet's answer.

Answer (score 5):

> But it does, with LINQ, right?

No, it doesn't. There's an *extension method* on `IEnumerable<T>` of `First()`, but extension methods can't be called on `dynamic` values in the "normal" way.

However, you can use it as a normal static method:

```
KeyValuePair<string, object> temp = Enumerable.First(result["success"]);
```

That will still be bound dynamically, mind you - whereas when you *cast* `result["success"]`, after the cast everything is just statically typed.

Comment: thanks Jon, its always a pleasure to have you around.